# Why wont my chrome extensions (that uses javascript) modify the target attributes for links?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write an extension that modifies the links on a webpage so that they open in the same tab instead of a new tab. My extension is made up of two files, *manifesto.json* and *main.js*.

The manifesto looks like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Quora Link Fixer",
  "description": "This extension modifies Quora links so that they open in the current tab.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.quora.com/*"],
      "js": ["main.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

And the javascript file looks like this:

```
console.log("Extension Loaded");

var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_self');
    console.log("Replaced target for link: " + anchors[i].href);
}
```

The console logs everything it's told to, however the targets never actually change and the links still open in new tabs.

Comment: Inspect the links in devtools and you'll see they have onclick attribute. Delete it.

Comment: *manifesto*???? Do you mean *manifest.json*?

Comment: Are you sure that something else does not change the target back? That you have not set some option to always open in a new tab, or an extension which does so?

Comment: @Makyen Yes, I do mean manifest. That's just an error in the post, not one I've actually made. It opens the links in a new tab for every user.

Comment: @wOxxOm Wouldn't I have to do this every time I open the page?

Comment: Have you done what wOxxOm suggested and inspected the element in DevTools to see if there is a `onclick` attribute, or attached `click` listener. Have you looked for `click` listeners on ancestor elements? Have you tried changing this manually using DevTools to see if the change works? Have you looked in DevTools to see if your change was made and that it continues to exist?

Comment: I don't see anything like onclick or click (I'm not very fluent in dev-tool usage) however the links have target="_blank", in other words the extension fails to actually change the attribute.

Comment: try `anchors[i].target =  '_self';` instead - also, `console.log("Replaced target for link: " + anchors[i].href + ' ' + anchors[i].target);` ... if that logs what you expect, it could be some other code runs after your code perhaps?

Comment: @JaromandaX No luck I'm afraid. I added that to the log and it says the target is _self

Comment: well, your code works then. perhaps some other code (on that site) is changing it back?

Comment: @JaromandaX Perhaps. Although it's proving difficult to find though. On the hyperlinks, it has action_mousedown="QuestionLinkClickthrough" which presumably is a javascript function. However the web page imports dozens of scripts.

Comment: browser developer tools should let you find that function using a search

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix the issue by adding a timer to delay the running of the code. I concluded that a piece of code ingrained into the website sets the links target as _blank after the page has loaded and after my code was running.

So I put the javascript code in a function and delayed the function using setTimeout(function, milliseconds).

Outcome:

```
console.log("Quora Link Fixer Extension Loaded");

function fu(){
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
      anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '');
  }
}

setTimeout(fu, 2200);
```